# Comparing count data models?

Tags: aic, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, zero-inflation

I am trying to fit Negative binomial, Zero Inflated Negative Binomial, Negative Binomial Hurdle, and Random effects negative binomial. Here is the value of AIC for different model:

Negative Binomial: 29178
ZINB: 27378.85
Hurdle Model NB: 28525.85
Random effects negative binomial: 31969.2

As far as I know lower the AIC, better the model. Is it true if I compare different types of model? Can I use AIC for comparing Random effect and fixed effect Negative Binomial Regression? Is there any other way to compare models?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have zero inflation you can also estimate the expected number of zeroes under each and compare with the observed,.

Comment: "Is there any other way to compare models?" — Yes, lots. [Model selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection) is a topic unto itself.